# 2 attempts to draw 2 kings

Tags: probability

What is the probability of drawing 2 kings in a row given 2 attempts?

The attempts are without replacement. So you draw 2 cards see if those are 2 kings. If not, try again.

I split this into cases:

Case 1: Draw 2 kings on 1st try (including possibility of 2 kings on 2nd try)

Case 2: Draw 2 kings on 2nd try given less than 2 kings were drawn on 2nd try

P(Case 1) = $\binom{4}{2} / \binom{52}{2}$

Explanation: From 4 kings, choose 2. From 52 cards, choose 2.

P(Case 2) = $[\binom{48}{2} /  \binom{52}{2} ] [ \binom{4}{2} / \binom{50}{2} ] +$ (for zero kings in 1st 2 draws)

Explanation: Draw 2 non-kings. Numer: From 48 non-kings, choose 2. Denom: From 52 cards, choose 2.

Then, draw 2 kings. Numer: From 4 kings, choose 2. Denom: From 50 remaining cards, choose 2.

$[\binom{48}{1} \binom{4}{1} /  \binom{52}{2} ] [ \binom{3}{2} / \binom{50}{2} ]$ (for one king in 1st 2 draws)

Explanation: Draw 1 king and 1 non-king. Numer: From 48 non-kings, choose 1. From 4 kings, choose 1. Denom: From 52 cards, choose 2.

Then, draw 2 kings. Numer: From 3 kings, choose 2. Denom: From 50 remaining cards, choose 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(Case 1)=\frac{4}{52}\times\frac{3}{51}=\frac{12}{2652}$ (this is equal to what you calculated)

Split up case 2 into two cases:

2.1: Draw 0 kings on first try ($P=\frac{48}{52}\times\frac{47}{51}=\frac{2256}{2652}$), 2 kings on 2nd try.

2.2: Draw 1 king on first try ($P=2\times\frac{48}{52}\times\frac{4}{51}=\frac{384}{2652}$), 2 kings on 2nd try.

$P(Case 2.1)=\frac{2256}{2652}\times\frac{4}{50}\times\frac{3}{49}=\frac{27072}{6497400}$

$P(Case 2.2)=\frac{384}{2652}\times\frac{3}{50}\times\frac{2}{49}=\frac{2304}{6497400}$

$P(Case1)+P(Case2.1)+P(Case2.2)\approx 0.0090461$

This is how I would have done it.

Comment: 2.1 is the same...

Comment: What do you mean? The same as what?

Comment: And 2.2 is the same. Yaaayyy!

Comment: I'll wait for others' answers. Maybe we both did it wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, I didn't check whether we had the same results, because your notation confused me.

Comment: By all means, please do. Probability is not my strongest area.

Comment: *looks up profile* Your highschool teaches probability but not combination notation? Also dude, you've got a bright future in STEM.